# Chart.js - Bar values showing on the middle of bar

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have this default bar chart and it is showing bar values inside bar. I don´t want that to be shown

[image]

This is the code of chart:

```
myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: datasets
  },
  options: {
      scales: {
          yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero:true
              }
          }]
      },
      maintainAspectRatio: false
  }
});
```

There is any option to disable this behaviour?

Best Regards

Comment: @WhiteHat chart code added

Comment: thanks for your attention but the problem is solved. I had the datalabel-plugin imported to my scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

There was included in scripts the datalabels plugin and was writting the value on the bar.